# Recuperar EditText de páginas de ViewPager

Tags: android

Estou com um problema aqui que é o seguinte, tenho uma Activity (estendendo de `FragmentActivity`) que possui um `ViewPager` usando `SectionsPagerAdapter` como adaptador.
Consigo criar quantas páginas precisar e passar dados para elas, o meu problema é conseguir capturar os dados gravados nos campos.

Por exemplo, ao trocar de página gostaria de já gravar o que foi digitado nos campos da tela atual, antes de ir para a Tela 2.

Ou através de um `Button`, clicar e já gravar o que foi digitado.

Não sei como obter os `EditText` das páginas.

Olha o código:

**Código da Activity**

```
package br.example.teste;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import br.example.modelo.Abastecimento;
import br.example.modelo.Atendimento;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class AbastecimentoFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    private Context contexto;
    private static LinearLayout layoutAnimado;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_PRODUTOS = 1;
    private Atendimento atendParaSerAlterado = null;
    private List<Abastecimento> abastecimentos;
    private Abastecimento abastecimento = null;
    private int qtd_molas;
    private static String[] lista_prods = new String[] {"MAQ BEB QUENTE BARI 220 NV","MAQ.PREP.BEB.Q.XM240E/4","MAQUINA LANCHE AMS  M"};
    //private static final String[] PRODUTOS = new String[] {"MAQ BEB QUENTE BARI 220 NV","MAQ.PREP.BEB.Q.XM240E/4","MAQUINA LANCHE AMS  M"};


    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abastecimento);

        contexto = this;  
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        atendParaSerAlterado = (Atendimento) intent.getSerializableExtra("atendimento");
        //abastecimento = (Abastecimento) intent.getSerializableExtra("abastecimento");
        abastecimentos = atendParaSerAlterado.getAbastecimento();

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        qtd_molas = extras.getInt("qtd_molas");
        if (qtd_molas == 0){
            qtd_molas = 5;
        }

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        //mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
                // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
                // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
                // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.
                //abastecimento.setAbastecido(mViewPager.);     //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                Log.i("FRAGMENT","Alterando tela -> " +position+1);
                mViewPager.getCurrentItem();


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();

            Abastecimento abast = (Abastecimento) abastecimentos.get(position);
            abast.setSaldo(String.valueOf(position));


            // passar aqui argumentos para campos serem preenchidos
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            args.putInt("num", position + 1);
            args.putSerializable("abastecimento", abast);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return qtd_molas;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            int pos = position + 1;

            return "Mola " +pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate (ViewGroup container){
            Log.i("STARTUPDATE","STARTUPDATE");
            EditText saldo = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EdtSaldo);
            EditText retirado = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EdtRetirado);
            EditText abastecido = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EdtAbastecido);    
            EditText descarte = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EdtDescarte);

            //mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0).getArguments();
            //this.getCount();
            //mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            //Abastecimento abast = (Abastecimento) abastecimentos.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            //abast.setAbastecido(abastecido.getText().toString());

        }

        /*
        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("FINISHUPDATE","FINISHUPDATE");
            //EditText saldo = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EdtSaldo);

        }
        */
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
            //TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            //dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            int num = getArguments().getInt("num");

            Abastecimento abast = (Abastecimento) getArguments().getSerializable("abastecimento");

            // layout animado
            layoutAnimado = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.animado);

            // campos do layout - preencher aqui os valores se necessario
            EditText saldo = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EdtSaldo);
            saldo.setText(abast.getSaldo());

            EditText retirado = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EdtRetirado);
            retirado.setText(abast.getRetirado());

            EditText abastecido = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EdtAbastecido);
            abastecido.setText(abast.getAbastecido());

            EditText descarte = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EdtDescarte);
            descarte.setText(abast.getDescarte());

            // alterar o produto da mola
            ImageView mola = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btMola);
            mola.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){

                    Intent edicao = new Intent(getActivity(),ListaProdutosActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult( edicao,ACTIVITY_PRODUTOS );

                }
            });

            mostrar();

            return rootView;
        }


        // na destruicao da view - grava os dados
        @Override
        public void onDestroyView(){
            super.onDestroyView();
            Log.i("ONDESTROYVIEW","DESTRUINDO A VIEW");

        }

    }


    // verificar
    public static void mostrar(){
        if (layoutAnimado.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            animar(true);
            layoutAnimado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public static void animar(boolean mostrar){
        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        Animation animation = null;
        if (mostrar){
            //desde la esquina inferior derecha a la superior izquierda
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        }

        //duración en milisegundos
        animation.setDuration(500);
        set.addAnimation(animation);
        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);

        layoutAnimado.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        layoutAnimado.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    //
    public void salvaForm(View view){
        Log.i("salvaForm","salvaForm");
        mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        Abastecimento abast = (Abastecimento) abastecimentos.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

        // como obter os edittext dos fragments?
        //mViewPager

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int codigo, int resultado, Intent it){
           super.onActivityResult(codigo, resultado, it);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Log.i("onBackPressed","onBackPressed"); 
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

**Código do Layout XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btMola"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/animado"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"  >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"  >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_acao_refresh" />

                <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/EdtSaldo"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:hint="Saldo"
                     android:background="@drawable/border" 
                     android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"  >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_acao_refresh" />

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/EdtRetirado"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:ems="10"
                  android:hint="Retirado"
                  android:background="@drawable/border" 
                  android:inputType="number" />
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"  > 

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_acao_refresh" />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/EdtAbastecido"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="Abastecido"
              android:background="@drawable/border" 
              android:inputType="number" />
          </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"  > 

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_acao_refresh" />
                <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/EdtDescarte"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:ems="10"
                      android:hint="Vencido/Avaria"
                      android:background="@drawable/border" 
                      android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"  > 

                  <Button
                   android:id="@+id/btnSalvar"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:onClick="salvaForm"
                   android:text="Salvar" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Jackson, recomendo usar o `OnPageChangeListener` no `ViewPager`. Vi que esta usando, não esta funcionando? Mas eu também recomendo que mude a forma como está seu Adapter. Guarde as instâncias dos Fragments em uma lista, senão você perderá os dados do Fragment ao navegar no ViewPager. Dê uma olhada nos métodos `onDestroyView` e `onSaveInstanceState` do Fragment, podem te ajudar se vc reutilizar os Fragments com a lista.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta! Resolvi de outra forma, para o aplicativo que tenho essa tipo de tela não seria mais adequado, resolvi utilizando uma tela com GridView.